# regex to catch substring in a line and change output with sed

Tags: regex, sed, regex-greedy

I am trying to put together a regex that will find a substring that has the following format:

1. [a-z].* ('x' number of lowercase letters)
2. A '-' sign [a-z].*
3. ('x' number of lower case letters [0-9].*
4. ('x' number of numbers from 0 to 9)

Anything else in the line that follows this substring (including space or ',') would not be caught by the regex and then I would add a new line to the results so they are in a list.

If this regex works the way I would like then from the following string

```
file.txt: hostname abcd-efg123, zfdh-eif23 , reox-bmo552, 'coor-dto201',
```

I would receive this output

```
abcd-efg123
zfdh-eif23
reox-bmo552
coor-dto201
```

This is what I have so far. I'm trying to use the regex and then store the result as as two variables which I can then put back into sed. I'm not getting the results I expected.

The regex/sed I am using is

```
sed 's/\([a-z].*\)-\([a-z].*[0-9].*\)/\2 \1 \n/g'
```

Here is the command straight from the prompt

```
macbook:~ user$ echo "file.txt: hostname abcd-efg123, zfdh-eif23 , reox-bmo552, 'coor-dto201'," | sed 's/\([a-z].*\)-\([a-z].*[0-9].*\)/\2 \1 \n/g'
dto201', file.txt: hostname abcd-efg123, zfdh-eif23 , reox-bmo552, 'coor n
```

Comment: `[a-z].*` does not mean "any number of lowercase letters" : it means "a lowercase letter, followed by any number of characters". The any `*` quantifier applies to the previous token, `.`, which is the regex's 'joker', that will match any character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the regex I would use to match :

```
[a-z]*-[a-z]*[0-9]*
```

The main problem in your regex was the use of `.*` where you obviously meant `*`. As I commented, `*` is the quantifier that means "any number of times (including 0)", while `.` is the "any character" wildcard. You want to apply the quantifier to your previous character class rather than to `.`, the `.` has no reason to be here.

Note that using `*` includes 0 repetition, so the regex would match a single dash, which might not be to your taste.
Maybe you could be more specific, with a regex along those lines :

```
[a-z]{4}-[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2,3}
```

Here instead of using `*` as a quantifier, we use numbers between curly brackets : they give us the possibility to specify an exact number of repetitions (i.e. `.{4}` means "any 4 characters") or a range of repetitions (i.e. `[0-9]{2,6}` means "2 to 6 digits"). You could also use `+`, a quantifier that means "at least one time", as mentioned by Kenavoz.

And here's how I would use it in a linux command :

```
grep -o '[a-z]*-[a-z]*[0-9]*'
```

or

```
grep -Eo '[a-z]{4}-[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2,3}'
```

Here it is in action :

```
$ echo "file.txt: hostname abcd-efg123, zfdh-eif23 , reox-bmo552, 'coor-dto201'," | grep -o '[a-z]*-[a-z]*[0-9]*'
abcd-efg123
zfdh-eif23
reox-bmo552
coor-dto201
```

Or with the more specific regex :

```
$ echo "file.txt: hostname abcd-efg123, zfdh-eif23 , reox-bmo552, 'coor-dto201'," | grep -Eo "[a-z]{4}-[a-z]{3}[0-9]{2,3}"
abcd-efg123
zfdh-eif23
reox-bmo552
coor-dto201
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered using grep to do it. Nice idea.

Comment: You're welcome. `sed` isn't well suited to extract multiple parts of a single line, and is generally overkill when all you need is to extract data.

Comment: Because `*` is for zero or more character, `-efg` will be matched. And applied to `hostname -, -, -, -`, all `-` will be output.

Comment: @Kenavoz thanks for your input, but that is the exact point of my second paragraph.

Comment: You may suggest a pattern for one or more character. ie: `grep -o '[a-z][a-z]*-[a-z][a-z]*[0-9][0-9]*' file` or `grep -o '[a-z]\+-[a-z]\+[0-9]\+' file`.